# Is this layout possible with grid in XamarinForm?

Tags: xamarin, grid

[image]

I want to create a grid layout with the following structure: 2 rows and 1 column. I would like to place a yellow control on top of the grid, which is not constrained by the grid.

The yellow control indicates the top layered state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the grid into the AbsoluteLayout and then use another control to cover the grid. Such as:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App23.Page2">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
          <AbsoluteLayout HeightRequest="600">
            <Grid AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,600,400" RowSpacing="0">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="7*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Fill" BackgroundColor="Green" Grid.Row="0"/>
                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Fill" BackgroundColor="Blue" Grid.Row="1"/>
            </Grid>
            <StackLayout  BackgroundColor="Red"
                         AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,140,140"/>
          </AbsoluteLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

And the result image:

[image]

**Update 1:**

You can use the [TranslationX property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.visualelement.translationx?view=xamarin-forms) and the [Custom Animation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/animation/custom) to move the red stacklayout. Such as

In the xaml:

```
<StackLayout x:Name="red" BackgroundColor="Red"
                         AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,140,140"/>
```

In the code behind:

```
var a = new Animation(v => red.TranslationX= v, 0, 100);
a.Commit(this, "Test", 16, 2000, Easing.CubicIn);
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. Your question has been resolved. I'd like to ask an additional question. How do I move the red position all the way to the right?

Comment: The `AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,140,140"` first 0 means the X coordinate of the red. So you can change the value of it to make it move to the right. @하하파파

Comment: You can check the update part in my answer. @하하파파

Comment: I have one more question. If the size of the parent changes, the screen size of the child also changes according to the ratio defined in AbsoluteLayout. Is there a way to keep it constant?

Comment: Do you mean the red part? @하하파파

Comment: Could you please post an new question to show more details? Because the `AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,140,140"`'s four parameters are X, Y, WidthRequest and HeightRequest. The size  shouldn't auto changed. @하하파파